# NGINX Is redirecting to localhost:3000

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, ssl, ruby-on-rails, certbot

I'm using ruby on rails in a docker container running my website https://redrebelgames.com on port 3000. I'm trying to setup NGINX to redirect http:// traffic to https:// and redirect port 80 to port 3000. It's working if you go directly to the IP address: 143.244.156.208. It's even redirecting the traffic to port 80. However, some of the photos are not loading as seen below:
[image]

And the domain itself is not working. What's wrong with my configuration in /etc/nginx/sites-available/default? You can see the inner of the file below:

```
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/
# https://wiki.debian.org/Nginx/DirectoryStructure
#
# In most cases, administrators will remove this file from sites-enabled/ and
# leave it as reference inside of sites-available where it will continue to be
# updated by the nginx packaging team.
#
# This file will automatically load configuration files provided by other
# applications, such as Drupal or Wordpress. These applications will be made
# available underneath a path with that package name, such as /drupal8.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    # root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    # index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        # proxy_http_version 1.1;
        # proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        # proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        # proxy_set_header Host $host;
        # proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        #try_files $uri $uri/ =403;
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    #   # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#   listen 80;
#   listen [::]:80;
#
#   server_name example.com;
#
#   root /var/www/example.com;
#   index index.html;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}

server {

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    # root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    # index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name redrebelgames.com; # managed by Certbot


    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        # proxy_http_version 1.1;
        # proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        # proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        # proxy_set_header Host $host;
        # proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    #   # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}


    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/redrebelgames.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/redrebelgames.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = redrebelgames.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80 ;
    listen [::]:80 ;
    server_name redrebelgames.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Comment: *"I'm trying to setup NGINX to redirect http:// traffic to https:// and __redirect__ port 80 to port 3000."* - No. You are trying to __proxy__ port 80 to port 3000 as can be seen by the `proxy_pass` directive. __Redirect__ means to instruct the browser to visit a different URL, which is impossible in your case since `localhost:3000` is only accessible from the local machine. __Proxy__ means to pass the clients request to the internal server and pass the servers response back to the client. This way the internal server on localhost gets visible from the outside.

Comment: Are you still having a problem? Your site loads fine, with no sign of inappropriate redirects.

Comment: On my machine it's still redirecting to https://localhost:3000. Do you know what's wrong?